# Best / most efficient way to filter objects

Tags: objective-c, loops, annotations

In my app Im showing multiple annoations on a map. I have lots of different annotations but basically I have 12 different kind of annotations with each its own image (so 12 different annotation images).

Now in my current code I subclassed MKAnnotation and gave it a property which i called "identifier" and when I create an annotation this identifier would be set to the appropriate value so later I could later filter a specific group of annotations and give them the right images in viewForAnnotation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
CustomAnnotation *pin = annotation;
MKAnnotationView *pinView=nil;

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

    return nil;
}
else if ([pin.identifier isEqualToString:@"tree"]) { //give annotation a tree image
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"OwnerAnnotationString"];
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"OwnerAnnotationString"];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamedForDevice:@"tree"];
    pinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -53/2);
    return pinView;
}
else if ([pin.identifier isEqualToString:@"house"]){ //give annotation a house image
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"SmallGoldPinStringAnkeren"];
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"anotheridentifier"];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamedForDevice:@"house"];
    pinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(8, -43/2);

    return pinView;
}
//and so on
```

I don't like this else if and the filtering process is really inefficient so I was wondering what the best and quickest way is to set the image for different annotations.

And last this example is done with annotations but I've run into this scenario multiple times now so actually my question is:

What is the best way to check what kind of object you're interacting with so you can set the appropriate values for that specific object in Objective-C.

Comment: 1: What filtering process is really slow? 2: You can't really escape the fact that you need to check at some point some value to determine which image will be assige ed

Comment: Maybe it's not slow but I was just thinking that all these if and else if aren't a nice way of programming it. It just looks bad and was wondering if there was a way to cut my code in half.

Comment: You can certainly factor it ou into some tertiary object. You will end up with nicer lookig code in the viewController, and better seperations of concerns. But the question then is whether the overhead for making that is really worth the effort if you really only have a couple (say, <10) images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving each annotation an identifier, place them in an NSmutableArray and place that array in an NS(Mutable)Dictionary. Have the key in that dictionary be what you have now as your identifier. This way the annotations are already sorted on creation, and if you need them all, in one array, you can simply create a new mutable array and add all objects from the arrays in the dictionary to it.